# GraalVM .exe file compiled with Gluon client-maven-plugin crashes with result -1073741819. How do I fix this?

Tags: java, javafx, gluon, graalvm

When I compile a JavaFX app through Gluon's client-maven-plugin into a Windows .exe file, the resulting application appears to randomly crash.

Experimentally, I've noticed crashes:

- When new windows are opened.
- When the app window moves around
- When I click another window.

The logs say that the app failed with result -1073741819. This appears to be some sort of memory error? No stack-traces are produced though, so I don't know how to investigate further.

There doesn't seem to be any rhyme or reason behind these crashes; they appear randomly and aren't reproducible.

I've also noticed (through print debugging) that it appears to crash in the following lines of Java code:

```
// On one thread:
synchronized (synchronizationObject) {
    synchronizationObject.wait();
    System.out.println("unlocked, continuing");
}

// ...

// On another thread:
synchronized (synchronizationObject) {
    synchronizationObject.notify();
    System.out.println("notified");
}
```

The print statements always seem to stop around the synchronized blocks, and then the program crashes.

I should note that running the program normally (without GraalVM) works perfectly.

Any thoughts?

EDIT 1:
The following is included at target\client\lo/process-run until end-1592766751282.log:

```
Process
=======
run until end

Command Line
============
C:\Users\Evan\Documents\ThreeBodySimulation\target\client\x86_64-windows\threebodysimulation.exe

Output
======


Result
======
result: -1073741819
```

The following is included at target\client\x86_64-windows\gvm\log under the run task heading:

```
[Sun Jun 21 15:11:31 EDT 2020][INFO] ==================== RUN TASK ====================
[Sun Jun 21 15:11:31 EDT 2020][FINE] PB Command for run until end: C:\Users\Evan\Documents\ThreeBodySimulation\target\client\x86_64-windows\threebodysimulation.exe
[Sun Jun 21 15:11:31 EDT 2020][FINE] Start process run until end...
[Sun Jun 21 15:12:31 EDT 2020][FINE] Result for run until end: -1073741819
[Sun Jun 21 15:12:31 EDT 2020][SEVERE] Process run until end failed with result: -1073741819
Check the log files under C:\Users\Evan\Documents\ThreeBodySimulation\target\client\x86_64-windows\gvm\log
And please check https://docs.gluonhq.com/client/ for more information.
[Sun Jun 21 15:12:31 EDT 2020][INFO] Logging process [run until end] to file: C:\Users\Evan\Documents\ThreeBodySimulation\target\client\log\process-run until end-1592766751282.log
```

Comment: If you run the project with `mvn client:run`, it should create a log file under `target/client/windows_x86-64/gvm/log`, that logs the RUN task. See if you find any exception?

Comment: @JoséPereda I've included the logs in an edit to the post. I don't see any exceptions, which is why I'm confused.

Comment: Can you add `<verbose>true</verbose>` to the plugin, and run again `mvn client:link client:run`?

Comment: @JoséPereda Okay, I added it. It still produces the exact same logs though. Looking through the logs for client:build, I see lots of references to "Exception raised in scope ForkJoinPool".

Comment: Maybe you can file an issue here: https://github.com/gluonhq/client-maven-plugin/issues and add that log?

Comment: @EvanZheng I don't know if you were able to deal with the problem, but I faced the exact same result code. If you're still interessted in trying: Could you check your `%PATH%` environment variable? Does it contain the path to another JDK?